# How to change hardware requirements in Windows Universal App?

Tags: windows, universal

I developed a Windows (10) Universal App and is deployed to the Store ([see here](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NBLGGH1Z6D2)). To my surprise people can't rate it, it gives this reason: "This app needs hardware your device doesn't have, hindering app performance. Rating and reviewing is turned off."

On the bottom of the page in the Store it says "Hardware requirements: Mouse, Touch". I did not configured that anywhere, and I can't find where to change it. I checked the appmanifest with the editor, and there is no tab "Hardware requirements".

This is my appmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="xxx" Publisher="CN=xxx" Version="1.1.10.0" />
    <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="xxxx" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
      <Properties>
        <DisplayName>StudioBrussel</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>BrechtB</PublisherDisplayName>
         <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
      </Properties>
      <Dependencies>
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
      </Dependencies>
      <Resources>
        <Resource Language="x-generate" />
      </Resources>
      <Applications>
        <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="StudioBrussel.App">
        <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Studio Brussel" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Listen to Studio Brussels with this app! Luister naar Studio Brussel met deze app! Écoutez Studio Brussel avec cette app!" BackgroundColor="#cb030b">
          <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
          </uap:DefaultTile>
          <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="#cb030b" />
          <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
            <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
            <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
        <uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
      </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
    </uap:VisualElements>
    <Extensions>
      <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="StudioBrussel.App">
        <BackgroundTasks>
          <Task Type="audio" />
        </BackgroundTasks>
       </Extension>
     </Extensions>
   </Application>
  </Applications>
 <Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />
 </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to change it, or is this a store bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, apparently the "hardware preferences" are not in the appmanifest anymore, but on [dev.windows.com](http://dev.windows.com) in the dashboard under submission => app properties => hardware preferences.